# AWS API Gateway : Allowing access to API from a lamba function in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have created a REST API using lambda and API gateway.

I want to give access for this API  to another lambda function which is running in another AWS account.

I was thinking to create `IAM based authorisation` for this API. But I am not sure if this cross-AWS account based IAM authorisation is feasible?

Any better suggestions?

Comment: assume a role, generate the secret keys and use the same to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume a role in the target account and then invoke the lambda directly using the temporary credentials. This method does not require an integration with API gateway.

You can also use IAM Authentication from anywhere if the API is publicly available. You will have to store the designated credentials.

Reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Comment: do you really need to access via api gateway